# Iptables bloque docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, etherpad

Since yesterday, I have restarted docker twice, in fact I have an Etherpad container which crashes with this error:

```
**ERROR: for etherpad  Cannot start service etherpad: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint etherpad_etherpad_1 (id_contenaire) 
(iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp -d 0/0 --dport 9001 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.21.0.3:9001 ! -i br-97eb28b9d479: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
 (exit status 1))**
```

,

visually it says port 9001 is in use by another process but netstat -tlunp | grep -w "9001" displays nothing on this port.

I googling a bit to find a solution but the only one is to restart docker: systemctl stop docker and systemctl start docker (which is not the best best),

thank you for everything

Comment: Do you have any other docker container running that use this port? What's the output of  `docker ps -a`

Comment: no other service uses port 9001

Answer (score 1):

I finally found where the error came from, in fact another inactive container (etherpad) was present to which the network of the present container was assigned (which created a confusion), had to:
`docker container ls`,
then

```
docker container rm id_container_last_etherpad
```

to delete this container, and
`docker network ls`, then `docker network rm etherpad_last_network`,

Hope this will help other people